# Batch file - two questions - exclude file names and move files in a special folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch that scans a folder and puts the files in folders depending of the first letter of each file :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Fichiers non déplacés
set noms = gamelist.bmp test.gif truc.pdf

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('DIR /B /A:-D "%cd%\*"') do IF NOT "%%A"=="%~nx0" ( IF NOT "%%A" in %noms% (

  set "FIRSTCHAR=%%~nA"
  set "FIRSTCHAR=!FIRSTCHAR:~0,1!"
  IF NOT EXIST "%cd%\!FIRSTCHAR!" MD "%cd%\!FIRSTCHAR!"
  MOVE "%cd%\%%A" "%cd%\!FIRSTCHAR!"
  
))
```

I have two noob questions I gave all I have to make this script lol) :

- I created an array named "noms" that I want to use to put filenames that won't be affected by the script (they won't be moved in the folder created by the script). Unfortunately, my "IF NOT "%%A" in %noms%" condition doesn't work. What is wrong please ?
- Second question : do you think it's possible to put all the files that begin by a number in a unique folder, "0-9" for instance ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: ```set noms = gamelist.bmp test.gif truc.pdf```, and ```IF NOT "%%A" in %noms%``` are not correct syntax. Please open a Command Prompt window, type each of your commands, one at a time, followed by the help option, `/?`, then press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out how they work. e.g. `set /?`; `if /?`.

Comment: Well thanks, I pu '''set noms = "gamelist.bmp test.gif truc.pdf"''' for instance, but I don't find the error

Answer (score 0):

```
set "noms=gamelist.bmp test.gif truc.pdf"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('DIR /B /A:-D "%cd%\*"') do (
 set "mouvement=O"
 for %%Q in ("%~nx0" %noms%) do if /i "%%~Q"=="%%~nxA" set "mouvement="
 if defined mouvement (
```

Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

`mouvement` is initialised to a value (any value will do) for each filename, but if the filename matches any of the values in `noms` or the batch filename `%~nx0` then it is set to *nothing* and becomes not defined.